# No data passed from the profile

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

Im trying to implement profiles in Spring and for reason I dont understand I cannot pass the URL from choosen profile to applicartion. 
The application.yml:

```
    spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: 'OFF'
  profiles:
    active: demo_prod
(…)
spring:
  profiles: demo_prod
(…)
mUrl: "http://localhost:8081/private/configuration"
```

The BasicConfiguration:

```
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties

public class BasicConfiguration {

    @Value("${mURL}")
    private static String mURL; 

    public static String getMURL() {
        return mURL;
    }
```

CentralService:

```
    @Service
public class CentralServiceImpl implements CentralServiceAdapter {

private final String URL = BasicConfiguration.getMURL();    //Here debbuging shows URL: null


@Override
public void sendMAttributes(MAttributesDTO mAttributesDTO) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);    //Here debbuging shows URL: null
(…)
```

This URL is not passed, Postman shows error and breakpoint/debugging shows „URL null”. What I,m doing wrong? It seems that profile „demo_prod” is not choosen or the respecitve URL is not passed to application. I have no idea how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with spring profiles. This is basic spring injection at play.

The reason it is not working is because your variable is static.

```
@Value("${mURL}")
private static String mURL;
```

static is evil in terms of Spring. Avoid static as far as possible. Spring doesn't inject values to static variables. If you still wish to do it, there is a workaroud. You can do it using setter method

```
private static String mURL; 

@Value("${mURL}")
public void setMUrl(String url){
   mURL = url;
}
```

And lastly(Not related to this issue). When you are using

```
@ConfigurationProperties
```

avoid `@Value`, this defeats the pupose of using ConfigurationProperties